# Get Corresponding OSM Node IDS from list of Lat,Long (CSV): Map Matching

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine, map-matching

I have a list of (lat,lng) coordinates. I want to map match them and get their corresponding OSM node ids? How can i do that using OSRM or any other map matching algorithm?

Comment: Are you restricted to OSRM? I would rather use PostGIS for that, but I guess there are multiple possibilities ...

Comment: Dear @jakob Miksch, No i am not restricted to OSRM, I am biased towards easy tools which has easy implementation smooth learning curve. . If you can further guide me how can i implement this using any tool.

Comment: in terms of pure *availability*, and only then usability, OSRM is the tool to use I'd say (I am biased towards OSRM, but there's Graphhopper as well!); there is no sophisticated map-matching algorithm implementation for the PostgreSQL/PostGIS/pgRouting environment. now, the OSRM project has plug&play docker container, as well as the overall very easy to use node.js bindings, including a very detailed documentation; where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: (note that I refer to 'map-matching' as the algorithmic way to find a best-fit between a GPS track and a network, considering the spatio-temporal properties of both inputs. this is different from (or better: more involved than) simply finding the *nearest* OSM nodes/ways)

Comment: @ThingumaBob i have seen the Graphhopper Map matching API Documentation, but it is taking only GPX files. I have used the OSRM Map Matching API as well where i have given lat/log one by one as test case but it is showing {'code': 'NoMatch'} as in output. I want to get node ID against all lat long.

Comment: @ThingumaBob is there any query in postgreSQL or POSTGIS where if i pass lat/long column and it return all the nearest nodeID against each lat/long? Need your prophetic remarks. Thanks :)

Comment: 'prophetic remarks' :-) well, to get results of the *match* API you need to feed it *all* GPS points (or at least a sequence)! go and read about map-matching (using the hidden-markov-model/chain and Viterby backtracing) to get familiar what OSRM actually does when you call the *match* API! however, when reading your other questions it may actually be possible that the OSM database has no mapped roads in your area, as suggested in the comments! please verify if the OSM data you use has the vector information of the road network you want to match against, or this endeavor is bound to fail!

Comment: PostGIS can easily find the nearest node to your GPS points (note that OSRM has a *nearest* API to do just that!), but the nearest node does not necessarily need to be the one you expect!

Comment: @ThingumaBob OSRM Nearest API worked for me in my scenario. Thank you so much for providing me your valuable knowledge.  Keep Shinning and blessed :)